# Какой push notif лучше

Tags: android, ios, push-уведомления

Добрый день посутпил заказ на проект в котором есть `remote push notification`.
Встал вопрос боком а какой сервис использовать ???`GCM` или `FCM`.
Какие плюсы и минусы?
Платформы `İos` и `Android`
Можно ли реализовать этот сервис самому?
Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит в вопросе _реализовать этот сервис самому_?

Comment: Тоестт написать gcm самому)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде это одно и тоже. Только FCM расширение GCM. Ну и если почитать документацию, то там рекомендуется переходить на FCM.

Так что если выбор только между этими двумя, то FCM. Если нет, то можно глянуть OneSignal, PushWoosh и другие.

Comment: а какой бы вы лчно посоветовали ?